# Run Rspec test block conditionally based on gem config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, config

I'm trying to add write a rspec test that is dependent on what the gem user has set as a configuration. So i want to run the test with a certain configuration.

This is the configuration:

```
Tasuku.configure do |config|
  config.update_answers = false
end
```

And this is the test that of course is only sensible when the configuration above is set to false:

```
  describe '#can_only_answer_each_question_once' do
    let!(:question)          { create :question_with_options }
    let!(:answer)           { create :question_answer, author: user, options: [question.options.first] }
    let!(:duplicate_answer) { build :question_answer, author: user, options: [question.options.first] }

    it 'prohibits an author from answering the same question more than once' do
      expect(duplicate_answer).not_to be_valid
    end

    it 'should have errors' do
      expect(duplicate_answer.errors_on(:base)).to eq [I18n.t('tasuku.taskables.questions.answers.already_answered')]
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution i ended ut using was setting the setting right before the it blocks in the correct context/describe block.

One example was is this:

```
  describe '#can_only_vote_once_for_single_choice_questions' do
    before(:all) do
      ::Tasuku.configure do |config|
        config.update_answers = false
      end
    end

    let!(:question) { create :question_with_options, multiple: false }
    let!(:answer)   { build :question_answer, author: user, options: [question.options.first, question.options.second] }

    it 'prohibits an author from answering the same question more than once' do
      expect(answer).not_to be_valid
    end

    it 'should have errors' do
      expect(answer.errors_on(:base)).to eq [I18n.t('tasuku.taskables.questions.answers.can_only_vote_once')]
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `RSpec`'s filters. More info here: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-8/docs/filtering/if-and-unless

For example:

```
describe '#can_only_answer_each_question_once', unless: answers_updated? do
```

Comment: Thank you, this is maybe a good alternative. However i realized need to run test for multiple scenarious but with different configurations. I'm updating my quesiton text to reflect this.